# Does installing with wubi affect performance?

Tags: installation, wubi

I just want to ask you, if I'm installing the Ubuntu beside the windows without any partition changes, using wubi does the ubuntu using more performance (CPU, memory, hard drive), or same as a normal installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since wubi uses a single file to store the Ubuntu installation on the NTFS drive IO will be slower

https://superuser.com/questions/222179/how-is-wubi-different-from-dual-booting-or-a-vm-image