# Installing Ubuntu with wubi or with standard installation

Tags: system-installation, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does installing with wubi affect performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34965/does-installing-with-wubi-affect-performance)

Hi,

I just want to ask you, if I'm installing the Ubuntu beside the windows without any partition changes, using wubi does the ubuntu using more performance (CPU, memory, hard drive), or same as a normal installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see a small performance decrease primarily in disk I/O

The disk image that a Wubi install runs out of sits on top of an NTFS filesystem which by nature can become fragmented.  Usually this is a negligable amount but I have seen it when developing code that does large amounts of I/O to the filesystem.

I also believe that hibernate and suspend are not fully supported on a Wubi install.